# AndroidRuntime: *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS

Tags: java, android, runtime, wifi-direct

I am developing an app based on WifiP2pService and I am getting the following error every once in a while, which causes the device to reboot. It only happens on the device which is establishing the communication and is happening on the devices with API>22.

This is the error I get :

```
2019-01-11 19:05:44.058 8111-8170/? E/AndroidRuntime: A FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: WifiP2pService
    java. lang. IllegalArgumentException: Null device
        at android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList.validateDevice(WifiP2pDeviceList.java:66)
        at android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList.remove(WifiP2pDeviceList.java:145)
        at com.android.server.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pServiceImp1SP2pStateMachineSGroupereatedState.processMessage(WifiP2pServiceImpl.java:3094) 
        at com.android.internal.util.StateMachineSSmHandler.processMsg(StateMachine.java:980)
        at com.android.internal.util.StateMachineSSmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:799)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java: 61)
```

Can anyone help me with this, I have already done my whole project and everything is working fine but this is really driving me crazy. It does not point to any part of my code. Anyways, thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this is old post. But I have exactly same issue with Android Nougat. Try to disable IPv6 in your router. it works for me...

Comment: @Sam thanks, I finished doing that project long time ago, but I will have it in mind in the future

Comment: @Sam can you please explain how u resolved the issue

Comment: @RoohiZuwairiyah I logged in to my router and disable IPv6. So, it just left with IP version 4.